# How to prevent datagridview from firing UserDeletingRow-event for every selected row?

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding, datagridview, event-handling

How can i stop the `DataGridView` control from triggering the `UserDeletingRow`-event  for every selected row after i've already consumed the first?

This grid is bound to objects from my wcf-webservice, i want to execute the delete method only once with all objects that should be deleted.

This event handler is triggered for every selected row which also triggers always "do you really want to delete"-messageboxes:

```
private void Grid_UserDeletingRow(object sender, DataGridViewRowCancelEventArgs e)
{
    switch (this.Type)
    {
        case AdminType.Channel:
            List<Channel> channels = GrdChannel.SelectedRows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>()
              .Select(row => (Channel)row.DataBoundItem).ToList();
            e.Cancel = !Delete_Channels(channels);
            break;
        // other types ...
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

This method calls the webservice after confirmation:

```
private bool Delete_Channels(List<Channel> channels)
{
    var msg = string.Format("Do you really want to delete {0}?", channels.Count == 1 ? "this channel" : "these channels");
    var title = channels.Count == 1 ? "Delete channel" : "Delete channels";
    bool yes = MessageBox.Show(msg, title, MessageBoxButtons.YesNo) == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Yes;
    if (yes)
    {
        using (var db = new ERP_ServiceClient())
            db.DeleteChannels(channels, this.IdUser);
        string message = string.Format("{0} deleted successfully: {1}"
                                      , channels.Count == 1 ? "Channel" : "Channels"
                                      , string.Join(",", channels.Select(p => p.Name)));
        channelBindingSource.Remove(channels);
        Main.ShowStatusMessage(message);
    }
    return yes;
}
```

Comment: So `Delete_Channels` etc. handle your deletion process but you want to combine this to `Delete_Objects` - for example?

Comment: You probabbly should consider to architect a behaviour you want. AFAIK there is no any event for multiple delete handling. Probabbly for you could be enough: 1. Get number of selected rows. 2. On every event decrease it and collect deletable row information into some list 3.On last row event add it to the collection, like all previous ones  and delete them al at once calling the service or a way you need to do.

Comment: @LukeHennerley: Yes and no. `Delete_Channels` deletes all channel-onjects via webservice after confirmation. But it takes all channels as `List<Channel>`, so i want to pass all selected channels at once.

Comment: @Tigran: I'm suprised that winforms is so cumbersome(my winforms experiences are rusty). I've hoped that there would be something builtin or more robust.

Comment: @TimSchmelter: There **may** be something , I just say that **I'm** not aware of something else. As mush as I remember from my experience, there isn't.

Comment: @Tigran: You may want to add an answer anyway, as long as it works. How do i know whether i have to initialize the `deleteCount` variable or i have to decrease it?

Comment: @TimSchmelter: this is a simple architecting stuff, don't think it really helps *you* to go ahead. You easily can do it by yourself too. :)

Comment: @TimSchmelter: good question. You may, at this point, try to deselct current row, so just *decrease* selected rows amount, if it's possible. So I get notification for one row, I deselct it, save into some collection and check either there is yet soemthing selected on the grid, if not, delete all that I've collected in collection before. Something like that. But, you have to try, if this really works for you.

Comment: @Tigran: Added my implementation of your suggestion, it seems to work well enough. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Ok, apparently there is no better approach(in terms of readability) so i've implemented Tigrans suggestion to use a count variable in the event handler and start deleting only after the last selected row triggered this event.

Here's the workaround:

```
private int _deleteCount = 0;
private bool _deleting = false;
private bool _reallyDelete = false;
private IEnumerable<object> _deleteEntities = null;

private void Grid_UserDeletingRow(object sender, DataGridViewRowCancelEventArgs e)
{
    DataGridView grid = (DataGridView)sender;

    if (!_deleting)
    {
        _deleting = true;
        _deleteCount = grid.SelectedRows.Count;
        _deleteEntities = grid.SelectedRows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>().Select(r => r.DataBoundItem).ToList();
        string msg = "";
        string title = "";

        switch (this.Type)
        {
            case AdminType.Channel:
                msg = string.Format("Do you really want to delete {0}?", _deleteCount == 1 ? "this channel" : "these channels");
                title = _deleteCount == 1 ? "Delete channel" : "Delete channels";
                break;
            // other types ...
            default:
                break;
        }
        _reallyDelete = MessageBox.Show(msg, title, MessageBoxButtons.YesNo) == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Yes;
    }

    e.Cancel = !_reallyDelete;

    // wait until all events are triggered before starting to delete
    if (--_deleteCount == 0)
    {
        switch (this.Type)
        {
            case AdminType.Channel:
                List<Channel> channels = _deleteEntities.Cast<Channel>().ToList();
                Delete_Channels(channels);
                break;
            // other types ...
            default:
                break;
        }
        _deleting = false;
        _reallyDelete = false;
        _deleteEntities = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: I think this has a bug. If you cancel the message box `Delete_Channels(channels)` is still called on the last iteration.

Answer (score 0):

rplace event of  UserDeletingRow with this event key_Down

if ( e.KeyValue == 46 ) // Delete Key

{
           e.Handled = MessageBox.Show( "Do you want really to delete the selected rows",
              "Confirm", MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Question ) != DialogResult.OK;
        }